# Преобразовать массив объектов в обычный массив

Tags: javascript

Доброй ночи. Подскажите где ошибаюсь? Нужно преобразовать массив объектов в обычный массив. Использую метод map.

```js
const data = [
{ 'search-word': 'аспирин' },
{ 'search-word': 'панангин' },
{ 'search-word': 'магний' },
{ 'search-word': 'кальций' },
{ 'search-word': 'цитрамон' },
{ 'search-word': 'аскофен' },
{ 'search-word': 'ношпа' },
{ 'search-word': 'анальгин' },
{ 'search-word': 'тизин' },
{ 'search-word': 'капатен' }
];

const arr = data.map((it) => it.search-word)

  console.log(arr)
```

Нужно получить следующую структуру ответа:
['аспирин', 'панангин', 'магний'...]

Comment: Вы применяете оператор вычитания `-` к значениям `it.search` и `word` — очевидно, ни того, ни другого не существует, вот и получается ошибка вычисления

Comment: Если вы хотите получить из объекта значение по ключу `search-word`, то пишите `it['search-word']`

Comment: Благодарю, понял в чем ошибка, запустил.

Answer (score 0):

```
const data = [
    { 'search-word': 'аспирин' },
    { 'search-word': 'панангин' },
    { 'search-word': 'магний' },
    { 'search-word': 'кальций' },
    { 'search-word': 'цитрамон' },
    { 'search-word': 'аскофен' },
    { 'search-word': 'ношпа' },
    { 'search-word': 'анальгин' },
    { 'search-word': 'тизин' },
    { 'search-word': 'капатен' }
    ];
const resoult = data.reduce((acum, item) => {
    for (const key in item) {
        acum.push(item[key])
    }
    return acum
},[])
console.log(resoult)
```

вывод

```
[
  'аспирин',  'панангин',
  'магний',   'кальций',
  'цитрамон', 'аскофен',
  'ношпа',    'анальгин',
  'тизин',    'капатен'
]
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]